# How to load required dependencies from subversion package

Tags: svn, dependencies, composer-php

I made my own composer package for laravel and use subversion to manage versions etc. Composer don't install the require and require-dev packages from our own package.

My main project composer

```
"name": "laravel/laravel",
  "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
  "keywords": [
    "framework",
    "laravel"
  ],
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "svn",
      "url": "https://path/to/package/title/"
    }
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "type": "project",
  "require": {
    "php": ">=7.2.0",
    "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",

    "company/package-name": "~1.0.0"
  },
```

the package composer.json

```
{
  "name": "company/package-name",
  "require": {
    "php": ">=7.2.0",

  },
  "require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^6.0",
    "orchestra/testbench": "^3.5"
  },

}
```

In this case orchestra/testbench is never installed. When I add it in the main project composer.json it will be installed, but when it is in the package composer.json, composer won't install it.

Can anybody tell me what's wrong with my set-up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`require-dev`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#require-dev) field is a "root-only" field and is only taken into consideration when you install a project as the [root package](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#root-package) (in other words, not as a dependency). Your "main project" is an example of a root package.

The reason `require-dev` is a "root-only" field is that is meant to specify the package requirements that would only be needed when someone wants to develop on this package or run its tests.

If you want `orchestra/testbench` to be installed, I'm assuming you want to use it in your main package to develop tests. In that case I would recommend adding it to your main package's `require-dev` field.

If you don't need the `orchestra/testbench` package in your main project, you don't need to worry about installing it. It won't be needed to use your `company/package-name` package.

Comment: thanks, i wonder why other packages also set require-dev to there composer file. Is this something like, keep in mind if you want to test this you need this package?

Comment: Yes, it's there for when someone wants to contribute or edit the package. Then they can run install the `require-dev` packages to be able to run the tests to see if their changes broke anything.

Answer (score 0):

In normal scenarios, dev packages should not be considered for the final build of your application. If you need this dependency maybe try moving it to the **require** section.